# Add or remove div class based on the sum of number input fields

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a working code to do what I need to, but it only works with jQuery 1.9.1 and I need it to work with jQuery 1.12.4, I've tried using noConflict, but it doesn't seem to want to work for me.

My goal is to calculate the sum of various number fields and add or remove a class depending on the value. In this case, if the sum of the number fields does not equal 8, then a class of "disabled" is added to a "add to cart" button.

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
    <script>
    $(document).on("change", ".addon-input_multiplier", function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".addon-input_multiplier").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    if (sum != 8) {
        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
     $(".single_add_to_cart_button").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? I think script not found the css for disable put in your stylesheet somewhere

> .disabled {
>           display: none;
>       }

```
<style type="text/css">
    .disabled {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on("change", ".addon-input_multiplier", function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".addon-input_multiplier").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    if (sum != 8) {
        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").addClass("disabled");
    } else {
     $(".single_add_to_cart_button").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
    </script>

    <form>
        <input type="number" name="aa" class="addon-input_multiplier">
        <input type="submit" name="sub" class="single_add_to_cart_button">
    </form>
```

Comment: The "disabled" class from my stylesheet works properly when the script is ran with jQuery 1.9.1.. I even tried adding the style directly using ```$('.single_add_to_cart_button').css('display','none');``` but it didn't work